# Get specific child inside the parent after_save in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models

Lead

```
class Lead < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :calls
end
```

Call

```
class Call < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :lead
end
```

On Call controller i need to update the Lead

```
def anything
  @call = Call.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @call.lead.update(lead_params)
            format.html { redirect_to seller_index_path, notice: 'Success' }
            format.json { render :index, status: :ok, location: @call.lead }
        else
            format.html { redirect_to seller_index_path, notice: 'Error' }
            format.json { render json: @call.lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Can i access the **specific** call in the after_save of Lead model?

I need to make some things inside the after_save with call object

Comment: No. But you can define a public method inside the Call and call it on `@call` after the update is successful. Like inside `if @call.lead.update(lead_params)` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't precise. Do you want to change the Call from controller (in this example its `@call`) or do you want to change other calls from this lead (e.g. `lead.calls.where(...).update_all(...)`)?

I assume, you meant the first issue, so to accomplish this, we will do these changes:

```
#in Lead model:
class Lead < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :specific_call # call it how it suits your business logic
  after_save :do_something_with_specific_call, if: :specific_call # you can use lambda in condition, e.g. if: -> { specific_call.present? }
  # your model code

  protected # or private
    def do_something_with_specific_call
      specific_call.update(...)
    end
end

#in controller method
def anything
  @call = Call.find(params[:id])
  @lead = @call.lead
  @lead.specific_call = @call # link @call to @lead virtual attribute

  respond_to do |format|
    if @lead.update(lead_params) # we can now use @lead
      format.html { redirect_to seller_index_path, notice: 'Success' }
      format.json { render :index, status: :ok, location: @lead } # same here
    else
      format.html { redirect_to seller_index_path, notice: 'Error' }
      format.json { render json: @lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } # same here
    end
  end
end
```

What we do here, is that we create a getter and setter methods (`attr_accessor`). If the model variable (`@lead#specific_call`) is set, then we will always run `#do_something_with_specific_call` method, so we set this variable in controller method.

This is also called a model virtual attribute.

Comment: Thank you, I was with the first problem. Your answer helped me a lot